# Custom devise controller is redirecting to wrong path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

My sign up routes are users/sign_up/speed1 etc. However if there is a devise error such as password does not match it redirects the user to '/users' path. Functionality it should redirect back to the same page and let the user re-enter a new password. Any update on this?

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    super
  end

  def update
    super
  end

  def speed1
    build_resource
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource
  end

  def speed2
    build_resource
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource
  end

  def speed3
    build_resource
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource
  end

  def speed4
    build_resource
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource
  end

  def speed5
    build_resource
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource
  end

  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    if current_user.role == 'speed1' || current_user.role == 'speed2' || current_user.role == 'speed3' || current_user.role == 'speed4' || current_user.role == 'speed5'
      '/subscription/new' # Or :prefix_to_your_route
    else
      '/'
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my route file that I have

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
  devise_scope :user do
    get 'users/sign_up/speed1', to: 'registrations#speed1'
    get 'users/sign_up/speed2', to: 'registrations#speed2'
    get 'users/sign_up/speed3', to: 'registrations#speed3'
    get 'users/sign_up/speed4', to: 'registrations#speed4'
    get 'users/sign_up/speed5', to: 'registrations#speed5'
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your `application_controller.rb`, it will return to the last page the user visited, or root_path

```
private

# If your model is called User
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  session["user_return_to"] || root_path
end
```

Comment: that doesnt do any good. If my user get a form error it redirect them to /users when in reality it should just reload on the same page the user was currently on

Comment: I think you are right, this method is after sign in, Im gonna do a few researches